# How can I help the Google Assistant recognise my action's name?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created an action called Sequematic.  The name is a combination of the words sequence and automatic.

Unfortunately when asking Google to 'talk to Sequematic' it has a hard time recognising the name.

Is there anything I can do to help with recognition of the name?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment there is very little that you can do to help Google Assistant with action recognition. The recognition is done by the voice recognition within the Google Assistant device itself and this is managed and trained by Google.

The only trick that I know is by playing around with the name pronunciation in you actions on google settings. This only works if the recognition is changing the name to a close match, something like "Sekuematik" because the recognition does not know how to handle the word. You could pick "Sekuamatik" as your action name and change the pronunciation to "Sequamatic".

[image]

While this works, it still changes your actions name, so your action name will be displayed as "Sekuematik" on any visual element in Google Assistant. So this trick might work for some people, but it is far from ideal.

The only other options you would have is wait for Google to update their voice recognition or maybe contact Google Assistant support and request their help to see if they can do something for your action name.

Comment: Thanks Jordi, that's what I suspected. I'll try contacting them directly, otherwise look at alternative names for the Action. Thanks for your comments.